# how to show all product when not apply any filter

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

class ProductListView(TemplateView):
template_name = "storefront/shop/product/list.html"

```
def get_context(self,request,id,slug, *args, **kwargs):
    category = get_object_or_404(Category,id=id,slug=slug)
    return category.get_option_list_context(request)

def get(self, request,id, slug, *args, **kwargs):
    template=self.template_name
    if request.GET.get('ajax'):
        # print("In ajax call")
        template = "storefront/shop/product/includes/sidebar.html"
    if request.GET.get('pagination_ajax'):
        template = "storefront/shop/product/includes/list-ajax.html"
    

  

    
    return render(request, template, self.get_context(request,id, slug, args, kwargs))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `ListView` and override the `get_queryset` method:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "storefront/shop/product/list.html"

    def get_queryset(self, **kwargs):
        object_list = Product.objects.all()
        if self.request.GET.get('some_filter'):
           # filter here
        return object_list
```